# Add a button dynamically in a HTML table row using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am receiving JSON data from an API and I am populating this data into an HTML table using vanilla javascript. I am trying to add a button dynamically to the end of each row to perform some functionality, I haven't found a way to do it.
Here is my function that populates the table with data

```
const showArtist = (data) => {
  let tableStructure = `<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Sr#</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Country</th>
           <th>Disambiguation</th>
           <th>Info</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
        </table>
      `;
  artistTable.innerHTML = tableStructure;
  let tableBody = document.getElementById("tbody");
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    let tr = "";

    tr += `<tr>
            <td>${i}</td>
            <td>${data[i].name}</td>
            <td>${data[i].country}</td>
            <td>${data[i].disambiguation}</td>

            <td><input type="button" value="" >Add</input></td>
          </tr>`;
    tableBody.innerHTML += tr;
  }
};
```

I have tried using the **appendChild** method but it doesn't work either.

Comment: ```append``` is Jquery methond, you should use ```appendChild``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: I have used the **appendChild** but it's not working either.

Comment: OK, I leave my answer with an example for you. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you comment you don't know how to use appendChild, I leave my answer here.

**Example Below**

```js
const artistTable = document.querySelector("#artistTable");

const data = [
  {
    name: "a",
    country: "bbb",
    disambiguation: "cc",
  },
  {
    name: "sss",
    country: "eeee",
    disambiguation: "dddddd",
  },
];

const showArtist = data => {
  let tableStructure = `<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Sr#</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Country</th>
           <th>Disambiguation</th>
           <th>Info</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
        </table>
      `;
  artistTable.innerHTML = tableStructure;
  let tableBody = document.getElementById("tbody");
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${i}</td>
    <td>${data[i].name}</td>
    <td>${data[i].country}</td>
    <td>${data[i].disambiguation}</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="" >Add</input></td>
   `;
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  }
};

showArtist(data);
```

```html
<div id="artistTable"></div>
```

Comment: In the code tr.innerHTMl=`<tr>.....</tr>`. Do we have to add tr tag again like you did or we can simply add the table data (td)

Comment: It worked and solved my problem. Thank you.@ikhvjs

Comment: @SureshMangs, I got your point, I updated my answer. I removed an extra tr tag inside the tr. innerHTML.

Comment: @ikhvjs That I know but I'm confused that If we have already created a tr element then why are we again adding tr into its innerHTML. I tried to run the code without the tr in the innerHTML of newly created tr and it worked fine

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes, this is what I was talking about. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```js
tableBody.innerHTML += tr;
```

with

```
tr = `<tr>
       <td>${i}</td>
       <td>${data[i].name}</td>
       <td>${data[i].country}</td>
       <td>${data[i].disambiguation}</td>
       <td><input type="button" value="" >Add</input></td>
      </tr>`;
const parser = new DOMParser(),
doc = parser.parseFromString(tr, "text/html");
tableBody.appendChild(doc.querySelector('tr'))
```

This should work.

More cleaner solution is to use combination of `document.createElement()`, `document.cloneNode()` and `document.appendChild()`.
Do something like

```
// Before for loop create tr and td element.
const tr = document.createElement('tr');
const td = document.createElement('td');

// Then inside for loop, Instead of using string definition,

let row = tr.cloneNode(true)
// Repeat these steps to create all <td>:
td1 = td.cloneNode(true);
td1.innerText = i // value
row.appendChld(td1) // Add all td to tr
tbody.appendChild(row)
```

Comment: I did but it shows  **DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'TBODY'.**  error

Comment: I have edited the answer. Try that. Or much cleaner method is to use combination of `document.createElement()` and `document.cloneNode()` and `document.appendChild()`.

Comment: I have tried the recent edit but the error remained the same. The `tr` is in a for loop and it works for all the other data except for the button